# Override a form in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

In Django admin I want to override and implement my own form for a model (e.g. Invoice model).

I want the invoice form to have auto-fill fields for customer name, product name and I also want to do custom validation (such as credit limit for a customer). How can I override the default form provided by Django admin and implement my own?

I am new to Django, I appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can override forms for django's built-in admin by setting form attribute of ModelAdmin to your own form class. See:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

It's also possible to override form template - have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options

If you're looking specifically for autocomplete I can recommend https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects

Comment: Is it possible to override the way the form looks as well? With auto complete feature for selected fields.

Comment: If you're looking for admin auto complete, I did not use django-ajax-selects, but [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is definitely worth it :)

Answer (score 36):

How to override a form in the django admin according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ['name']

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['age']
    form = PersonForm
```

Comment: Do I place this code in models.py or admin.py. Also where is the Person app coming is this referring to an app I created?

Comment: @KehlinSwain: Person is the Model. This code can live in admin.py, or an external form.py that you import from admin.py.

Comment: @AlMahdi if `add_form` is a method in the `admin.ModelAdmin` class, then I don't see why not.