# Django - Show foreign key value infront of form selection value in filter_horizontal selection

Tags: python, django, forms, admin

Noob here. In my "Student" model admin I have a filter_horizontal selection form that filters a field lessons_enrolled_in.

Lessons_enrolled_in is a many to many to Lessons model which has a many to many Courses model.

In my model admin filter-horizontal I want it to select the lesson (which it does) but I want the selections to simply list  "Course name - Lesson name" instead of just "Lesson name".

Do I need a custom form for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can define the `__unicode__` method in `Lesson`

```
class Lesson(models.Model):

    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.course.name, self.name)
```

or define your own form or form template as described here [stackoverflow.com/a/10041463/2028375](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10041463/2028375)

Comment: Yes thank you, I had done this, however I don't want it to be displayed everywhere just in one admin form.

Comment: Well then you either define your own form or form template as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10041463/2028375 or you refrain from printing the naked object in other places and always use the name attribute. Which is what I do when facing these problems, mainly because updating the form for every model change is a chore.

Comment: amended answer so it includes all the relevant info