# Django models – Setting up Categories, optional subcategories and products

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a **Django application** with products where each product belongs to a main category and **≥0** optional subcategories.

**For example:**

```
Product: Brandname All-stars
Subcategories: Sneakers, Lo-tops, trainers
Category: Shoes
```

For some generic products, we do not want a Subcategory, only a main Category.

My attempt allows the `subcategory` relation to be **optional**. However, when `adding a new Product in the admin` or in forms, all subcategories are available but I would like only the subcategories applicable to the chosen Category to be available.

E.G when adding a new raincoat, I do not want the Subcategories Sneakers or lo-tops available.

Any suggestions?

```
From django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(Subcategory, blank=True)
```

Comment: You have the relation specifying which is the parent category of a subcategory. So, would querying, upon selection of a category for a product, which are the subcategories having this category as parent would work for you?

Comment: When I read your description I would go for only 1 category per product, and then further filtering could be based on a tagging system where you only displat the tags used within that category

Comment: Well, if you want to filter available choices in form, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform), if you need to change forms in django's admin site, [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040442/override-a-form-in-django-admin)

Comment: Step 1: Validate that all subcategories belong to product category in `clean` method.
Step 2: Add js code that will filter out subcategories based on selected category.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I thought about tagging as well, but that would still take me back to the other suggestions, basically filtering the query and/or modifying the form and admin? I kept looking for a solution and am also looking into tree-based once, something I'm not familiar with.