# How to rename translation fields in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeltranslation

I have fields in model.py namely name,city which are registered with translation.So automatically two fields name_en and name_he are created in database. I want these fields to display as name_english and name_hebrew in admin portal of django.

In my settings.py :

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('he', gettext('Hebrew')),
)
```

Any approach to do so.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Translation field. But I think overriding Django admin form or using custom fields can help you.

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10041463/1923614)