# if statement for a specific field in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm rendering a form in a django template using this model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    has_max = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    max_size = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    DAYS = [
        ('Sundays', 'Sundays'),
        ('Mondays', 'Mondays'),
        ('Tuesdays', 'Tuesdays'),
        ('Wednesdays', 'Wednesdays'),
        ('Thursdays', 'Thursdays'),
        ('Fridays', 'Fridays'),
        ('Saturdays', 'Saturdays'),
    ]
    meeting_day = MultiSelectField(
        verbose_name = 'Meeting day(s)',
        choices=DAYS,
        max_choices=6,
        max_length=100
    )
    start_time = TimeField(widget=TimePickerInput)
    end_time = TimeField(widget=TimePickerInput)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And onto this template:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button>POST</button>
</form>
```

I have a couple of issues going forward:

My first issue is that I only want to have `max_size` be displayed in my template form if the user clicks `has_max`. Like a conditional, where once the user checks the box, changing `has_max` to `True` then they can enter in the max size of the group.

My second issue is that the `start_time` and `end_time` to render in my template or on the admin side. I'm not sure how `TimePickerInput` works, but right now, there are no fields in my template form or admin form that have those time fields.

Also, last thing, if I have both names the exact same (i.e., `('Sundays', 'Sundays'),` is it necessary to have both? Or can django figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Problem as I understand it You want to have this check box and when it will true the Field of `max_size` will appear this problem needs to solve with `javascript`

**Why ?**

Because if You use the `Django template` you will need to refresh the page when the user changes something and this will overload the server So you need to create an event with `js` when the use click on the `checkbox` it will disappear

> Also, last thing, if I have both names the exact same (i.e., ('Sundays', 'Sundays'), is it necessary to have both? Or can Django figure it out?

This part ... You need to know that the first value is the value will be stored in the database and the second value is the human-readable value this what will be displayed for the user in the form [Read This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

You must know you can't put widgets into your model if you want to add it add it to your from in Your `admin` or `form` files ... You will override the `AdminModel` in your `admin` file and change the `form`value [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040442/override-a-form-in-django-admin)